# Induction proof $n!>2n$ for all integers $n>3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, induction, factorial

I'm trying to solve it, but I'm stuck with

$$(k+1)k!>2(k+1)$$

Comment: You *have* to use the hypothesis of induction, i.e., $k!>2k$, with this $(k+1)!=(k+1)k!>(k+1)2k=2k^2+2k>2(k+1)$, which it's true for $k>3$.

Comment: Is your inequality $k!>2$ ?

Comment: Observe that $(k+1)\cdot k!=k\cdot k!+k!$. Now,  (1) $k\cdot k!>2k$ by induction hypothesis and since $k>1$  and (2) $k!>2$ since $k>2$. Can you do it from here?

Comment: It seems silly to insist on a proof by induction when clearly $n! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3  \cdots n > 2\cdot n$ for $n > 3$.

Comment: ... or even $n! > 2n$ iff $(n-1)! > 2$, which is true for $n-1> 2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base case: $4!=24 > 8 = 2\cdot 4$

Induction assumption: $k>3$ and $k!>2k$

$$\begin{align}
(k+1)! &= (k+1)k! \\
&>(k+1)2k  \tag{ind. hyp}\\
&>2(k+1) \\
\end{align}$$

Therefore the induction holds and $n!>2n$ for $n>3$.

As you can see this is a very loose lower bound on $n!$. We could achieve $n!>5n$ in essentially the same argument.

---

In fact that is so loose I'm wondering if the original intent was to claim that $n!>2^n$ for $n>3$. In which case the induction goes:

Base case: $4!=24 > 16 = 2^4$

Induction assumption: $k>3$ and $k!>2^k$

$$\begin{align}
(k+1)! &= (k+1)k! \\
&>(k+1)2^k  \tag{ind. hyp}\\
&>2^{k+1} \tag{$k\mathord+1>2$} \\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

According to our induction, we should have

$$(k+1)k!>(k+1)(2k)>2(k+1)$$

since we assume $k!>2k$.  Lastly, we check $k=4$.